# "col-sm-x" class divs not spanning their proper width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have three div elements in a single row. These three divs would be at 2 columns wide, 8 columns wide, and 2 columns wide from left to right in bootstrap. I have a container class div with a row class div nested inside of it. Inside of this row there are the three divs.

However, the columns are not spanning the widths they are supposed to. To illustrate my problem, look here:https://wizviper777.github.io/UniverseIdleActual/ The left and right divs should be 2 columns, and the middle div should be 8.

Here is the relevant html:

```
    <div class='container' id='asteroid-hub'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='container col-sm-2' id='asteroid-resources'>
          <p>Ore:0</p>
          <p>Metal:0</p>
          <p id='power-text'><strong>Power:0</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class='container col-sm-8' id='asteroid-buildings'>
          <button class='btn btn-default  bldg'>Mine</button>
          <button class='btn btn-default  bldg'>Refinery</button>
          <button class='btn btn-default  bldg'>Panel</button>
          <button class='btn btn-default  bldg'>Pumpjack</button>
          <button class='btn btn-default  bldg'>Generator</button>
          <button class='btn btn-default  bldg'>Bio Farm</button>
          <button class='btn btn-default  bldg'>Heating Plant</button>
        </div>
        <div class='container col-sm-2' id='asteroid-upgrades'>
          <p>Test</p>    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
    #asteroid-resources {
      border-right-color: black;
      border-right-style:solid;
      border-right-width:2px;
      height:86vh;
}

    #asteroid-upgrades {
      border-left: black 2px solid;
      margin:0px;
}

    .container-fluid {
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
}

    .container {
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
}

    .row{
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT: Using my code editor, I discovered that these divs are in fact properly sizing, but there is a mass of empty space to the right of the third div.

Comment: `sm` means only on small screens, did you consider `md` `lg`?

Comment: I have tested with md and lg to no avail so far.

Comment: ah, remove the `container` you are using wilth `col-sm`

Comment: remove the container class where exactly? I removed it on all 3 divs and still they are not of proper length.

Comment: You put a margin of 0 on your `.container`. Bootstrap defines the `margin-left` and `margin-right` as `auto`. That is how it has a centered container and the reason why you have all that space on the right. So just remove the `margin:0px;`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. However, is there a way to make it so that I can have no margin while still keeping the column system in place?

Comment: Do you want your container to stretch the full width of the page? Then you probably want `container-fluid` instead of `container`

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that by putting a margin:0px; on my container class, and giving the 3 divs container classes, I was causing space to appear on the right of the screen, ruining the column width system.

**Removing the margin:0px; and then changing the overarching container to a container-fluid allowed the columns to span the full width of the page and not have any empty margins.**

Comment: I don't know if you know this but Bootstrap has built-in classes for margins and paddings = `m-0, m-1... m-5, p-0 ...p-5, mx-0...mx-5, py-md-3, m-auto, my-auto, pb-1, pt-2, ml-lg-1, mr-lg-2` etc. Basically m = margin, p = padding, y = vertical, x = horizontal and t,r,b,l = top, right, bottom, left plus auto for centered-margins(not for padding) as well as setting it at specific breakpoints.